# Implement pipe in my shell

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I have read a lot a similar subjects and I have been searching for a long time, but I didn't find where is my problem, so I'm asking you some help :

I'm trying to implement a mini-shell, it's work pretty well, but I have one issue with the pipe implementation :

The prompt come back before that the pipe have finished its work :
    `/home/sim/t? ls | grep toto` prints `/home/sim/t? toto` (on the same line) instead of

```
toto
/home/sim/t?
```

If I add a sleep(1) (look in the commentary of the code) it works well, but I would like to find how to wait the good process, I tried a lot of things, but it didn't work...

The command `ls | wc` also prints nothing when it should.

Here is my code (sorry for the length, don't hesitate to ask for clarifications) :

```
# include <assert.h> 
# include <stdio.h> 
# include <stdlib.h> 
# include <unistd.h> 
# include <sys/stat.h> 
# include <sys/types.h> 
# include <fcntl.h> 
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <string.h>
enum { 
    MaxLigne = 1024,              
    MaxMot = MaxLigne / 2,       
    MaxDirs = 100,          
    MaxPathLength = 512,      
}; 
void decouper(char *, char *, char **, int); 
void affiche_prompt();
int in_array(char *, char **);
void executer_PATH(char **);
void usage(char *);

int 
main(int argc, char * argv[]){ 
    char ligne[MaxLigne]; 
    char * mot[MaxMot];
    char * mot2[MaxMot];
    int fd[2];
    int pipe_flag, i; 
    pid_t tmp, tmp_pipe;  

    for(affiche_prompt();fgets(ligne, sizeof ligne, stdin) != 0;affiche_prompt()) { 
        decouper(ligne, " \t\n", mot, MaxMot); 

        if (mot[0] == 0)  
            continue; 

        /* Is there a pipe? */
        pipe_flag = in_array("|", mot);
        if (pipe_flag > 0){
            if (pipe(fd) != 0)
               usage("Problème dans la création du pipe");

            if(mot[pipe_flag] == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, 
                    "Vous devez entrer une commande après le pipe (|)\n");
            }
            //Copy second instruction in an array
            i = 0;
            while(pipe_flag <= MaxMot) {        
                mot2[i] = mot[pipe_flag];
                pipe_flag++;
                i++;
            }   
        }     

        tmp = fork();   

        if (tmp < 0){ 
            perror("fork"); 
            continue; 
        }  

        if (tmp != 0){  

            if (pipe_flag > 0){ //ther is a pipe            
                tmp_pipe = fork(); //for the shell not to be closed after a pipe

                if (tmp_pipe < 0){ 
                    perror("fork"); 
                    continue; 
                }  

                if (tmp_pipe != 0){ 
                    while(wait(0) != tmp_pipe); 
                    // here is the problem because a 
                    // sleep(1); 
                    // makes the shell waits as it should
                    continue;
                }  

                close(fd[0]); 
                dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO); 
                close(fd[1]); 
                executer_PATH(mot);   
            }    
            while(wait(0) != tmp) ; 
            continue;   
        } 

        if (pipe_flag == 0){ //There is no pipe                      
            executer_PATH(mot); 
        }
        //there is one pipe
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        executer_PATH(mot2);                  
    } 
    printf("Bye\n"); 
    return 0; 
}


/* decouper  --  decouper une chaine en mots */ 
void 
decouper(char * ligne, char * separ, char * mot[], int maxmot){ 
  int i; 

  mot[0] = strtok(ligne, separ); 
  for(i = 1; mot[i - 1] != 0; i++){ 
    if (i == maxmot){ 
      usage("Erreur dans la fonction decouper: trop de mots"); 
      mot[i - 1] = 0; 
      break; 
    } 
    mot[i] = strtok(NULL, separ); 
  } 
} 

/* affiche_prompt 
    affect à la variable globale PROMPT "?" + le répertoire courant*/
void 
affiche_prompt(){
    char buffer[MaxPathLength];
    if (getcwd (buffer, MaxPathLength) == NULL) 
        usage("impossible de connaître le répertoire courant");
    printf("%s", strcat(buffer, "? ")); 
}

/* in_array --
    renvoie 0 si le mot n'est pas trouvé, la case suivante sinon */
int
in_array(char * mot_cherche, char ** mot)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= MaxMot; i++){ 
        if (mot[i] == 0) 
            break; 

        if (strcmp(mot[i], mot_cherche) == 0){  
            mot[i] = 0; 
            return i+1;
        } 
    }   
    return 0; 
}

/* executer_PATH -- essaye de lancer la commande donnée en argument avec les 
chemins enregistrés dans PATH */ 
void 
executer_PATH(char ** commande){ 
    int i; 
    char * dirs[MaxDirs]; 
    char pathname[MaxPathLength]; 

    /* Decouper PATH en repertoires */ 
    decouper(strdup(getenv("PATH")), ":", dirs, MaxDirs); 

    for(i = 0; dirs[i] != 0; i++){           
        snprintf(pathname, sizeof pathname, "%s/%s", dirs[i], commande[0]); 
        execv(pathname, commande); 
    } 
    /* Aucun exec n’a fonctionné */       
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: not found\n", commande[0]); 
    exit(1); 
} 

/* usage -- afficher un message d'erreur et sortir */
void 
usage(char * message)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
    exit(1);
}
```

Any comments on my code is welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Have you added print statements to see what is happening at key points (like just before the calls to `executer_PATH()`)?

Comment: yes, but without results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that `executer_PATH()` can return when it fails to execute the program, but only 3 of the 5 calls to it are followed by error handling code.  It would be better to have the function report the error and exit.  When that change is made, the shell executes plausibly.

Modifying `executer_PATH()` to:

```
void
executer_PATH(char **commande)
{
    int i;
    char *dirs[MaxDirs];
    char pathname[MaxPathLength];

    decouper(strdup(getenv("PATH")), ":", dirs, MaxDirs);

    for (i = 0; dirs[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        snprintf(pathname, sizeof pathname, "%s/%s", dirs[i], commande[0]);
        execv(pathname, commande);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to find a command for %s\n", commande[0]);
    exit(1);
}
```

Leads to output like the following:

```
/Users/jleffler/soq? ls | wkj
Failed to find a command for wkj
/Users/jleffler/soq? wkj | cat
Failed to find a command for wkj
/Users/jleffler/soq? wkj | lkq
Failed to find a command for lkq
Failed to find a command for wkj
/Users/jleffler/soq? Bye
```

I did remove the now superfluous error checking code after the calls to `executer_PATH()`, but the code change shown is sufficient to make things work reasonably well.  The problem is that the `executer_PATH()` without the error code ends up with a child still running (waiting for input?) while the parent is still waiting for the child to exit, which it won't.

---

The mildly modified variation of the revised code that is shown below:

1. Declares `affiche_prompt();` with a full prototype (with no arguments, it just says 'the function exists, but you know nothing about the argument list').
2. Defines `main()` with no arguments since they aren't used.
3. Prints diagnostic information about PID and command in `executer_PATH()`.
4. Captures and prints diagnostic information about PID and exit status in the waiting loops.
5. Modifies the logic in the inner `fork()` handling code to have `if (pid < 0)` and `else if (pid != 0)` and an `else`.  I prefer this, or perhaps `switch (pid) { case -1: ...; case 0: ...; default: ...; }`, to the organization you had.  I often create a function to be the action in each part of the `if` statement.  I didn't fix the outer code.

The result is output like this:

```
$ ./pipe43
/home/jleffler/soq? ls | sleep 4
Child 19300: sleep
Child 19301: ls
End-1: PID 19301 exit status 0x0000
End-2: PID 19300 exit status 0x0000
/home/jleffler/soq? sleep 4 | ls
Child 19318: ls
Child 19319: sleep
bash-assoc-arrays.sh  kwargs.py  pipe43    posixver.h  spc.py  tmn.c
data              makefile   pipe43.c  select.c    tmn
Got-1: PID 19318 exit status 0x0000
End-1: PID 19319 exit status 0x0000
End-2: PID -1 exit status 0x0000
/home/jleffler/soq? Bye
$
```

So far, so good.  Then I tried:

```
$ ./pipe43
/home/jleffler/soq? ls | cat
Child 19807: ls
Child 19806: cat
End-1: PID 19807 exit status 0x0000
bash-assoc-arrays.sh
data
kwargs.py
makefile
pipe43
pipe43.c
posixver.h
select.c
spc.py
tmn
tmn.c
```

And it didn't terminate until I interrupted it.  That indicates that you are not closing the pipe in the parent process — the shell that is doing the waiting.  I added lines:

```
close(fd[0]);
close(fd[1]);
```

before each of the `wait()` loops — now shown in the code below — though the second pair is redundant unless you remove the inner `wait()` loop.

With the extra closes in place, the output becomes:

```
$ ./pipe43
/home/jleffler/soq? ls | cat
Child 20111: cat
Child 20112: ls
bash-assoc-arrays.sh
data
kwargs.py
makefile
pipe43
pipe43.c
posixver.h
select.c
spc.py
tmn
tmn.c
End-1: PID 20112 exit status 0x0000
End-2: PID 20111 exit status 0x0000
/home/jleffler/soq? Bye
$
```

The revised code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {
    MaxLigne = 1024,
    MaxMot = MaxLigne / 2,
    MaxDirs = 100,
    MaxPathLength = 512,
};
void decouper(char *, char *, char **, int);
void affiche_prompt(void);
int in_array(char *, char **);
void executer_PATH(char **);
void usage(char *);

int
main(void)
{
    char ligne[MaxLigne];
    char * mot[MaxMot];
    char * mot2[MaxMot];
    int fd[2];
    int pipe_flag, i;
    pid_t tmp;

    for(affiche_prompt();fgets(ligne, sizeof ligne, stdin) != 0;affiche_prompt()) {
        decouper(ligne, " \t\n", mot, MaxMot);

        if (mot[0] == 0)
            continue;

        /* Is there a pipe? */
        pipe_flag = in_array("|", mot);
        if (pipe_flag > 0){
            if (pipe(fd) != 0)
               usage("Problème dans la création du pipe");

            if(mot[pipe_flag] == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                    "Vous devez entrer une commande après le pipe (|)\n");
            }
            //Copy second instruction in an array
            i = 0;
            while(pipe_flag <= MaxMot) {
                mot2[i] = mot[pipe_flag];
                pipe_flag++;
                i++;
            }
        }

        tmp = fork();

        if (tmp < 0){
            perror("fork");
            continue;
        }

        if (tmp != 0)
        {
            if (pipe_flag > 0){ //ther is a pipe
                pid_t pid2 = fork(); //for the shell not to be closed after a pipe

                if (pid2 < 0){
                    perror("fork");
                }
                else if (pid2 != 0){
                  close(fd[0]);
                  close(fd[1]);
                  int corpse;
                  int status;
                  while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != pid2 && corpse != -1)
                    fprintf(stderr, "Got-1: PID %d exit status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
                  fprintf(stderr, "End-1: PID %d exit status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
                }
                else
                {
                  close(fd[0]);
                  dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                  close(fd[1]);
                  executer_PATH(mot);
                }
            }
            {
              int corpse;
              int status;
              /* These closes are redundant until you remove the inner wait code */
              close(fd[0]);
              close(fd[1]);
              while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != tmp && corpse != -1)
                fprintf(stderr, "Got-2: PID %d exit status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
              fprintf(stderr, "End-2: PID %d exit status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
            }
            continue;
        }

        if (pipe_flag == 0){ //There is no pipe
            executer_PATH(mot);
        }
        //there is one pipe
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        executer_PATH(mot2);
    }
    printf("Bye\n");
    return 0;
}


/* decouper  --  decouper une chaine en mots */
void
decouper(char * ligne, char * separ, char * mot[], int maxmot){
  int i;

  mot[0] = strtok(ligne, separ);
  for(i = 1; mot[i - 1] != 0; i++){
    if (i == maxmot){
      usage("Erreur dans la fonction decouper: trop de mots");
      mot[i - 1] = 0;
      break;
    }
    mot[i] = strtok(NULL, separ);
  }
}

/* affiche_prompt
    affect à la variable globale PROMPT "?" + le répertoire courant*/
void
affiche_prompt(void){
    char buffer[MaxPathLength];
    if (getcwd (buffer, MaxPathLength) == NULL)
        usage("impossible de connaître le répertoire courant");
    printf("%s", strcat(buffer, "? "));
}

/* in_array --
    renvoie 0 si le mot n'est pas trouvé, la case suivante sinon */
int
in_array(char * mot_cherche, char ** mot)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= MaxMot; i++){
        if (mot[i] == 0)
            break;

        if (strcmp(mot[i], mot_cherche) == 0){
            mot[i] = 0;
            return i+1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* executer_PATH -- essaye de lancer la commande donnée en argument avec les
chemins enregistrés dans PATH */
void
executer_PATH(char ** commande){
    int i;
    char * dirs[MaxDirs];
    char pathname[MaxPathLength];
    fprintf(stderr, "Child %d: %s\n", (int)getpid(), commande[0]);

    /* Decouper PATH en repertoires */
    decouper(strdup(getenv("PATH")), ":", dirs, MaxDirs);

    for(i = 0; dirs[i] != 0; i++){
        snprintf(pathname, sizeof pathname, "%s/%s", dirs[i], commande[0]);
        execv(pathname, commande);
    }
    /* Aucun exec n’a fonctionné */
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: not found\n", commande[0]);
    exit(1);
}

/* usage -- afficher un message d'erreur et sortir */
void
usage(char * message)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: There is still the second problem, the prompt doesn't wait the end of the execs of the pipe. Do you think that I need to use waitpid instead of wait to avoid this?

Comment: Using `waitpid()` instead of `wait()` won't really change anything.  I've not followed your logic fully (it is rather tricky to follow), but it probably means your parent process isn't waiting for the correct child, and/or not all processes in the pipeline are children of the shell (they're children of a child of the shell).

Comment: I edited my code to make it more readable, and I added comments where the problem is, could you please have a look? Or should I start a new post?

Comment: In general, it is best not to damage the original code for a question; it spoils the answers.  It is better either to show the changes or to ask a new question.  Don't bother this time, but for future reference...

Comment: Thank you really a lot for your answer and for the good advices that you gave me. Ok for the first closes, it have to be in the code, but I don't understand the second closes, and why aren't they redundant if I remove the inner wait code, and which inner wait code? (Do you mean the diagnostic fprintf, what does it change?) Moreover, I still have the same problem, if I do a ls | grep a, sometimes, the prompt come back before the end of the print. Do you have any idea of where does it come from?

Comment: Can you characterize more accurately when the prompt comes back before the end of the output? I've not seen that behaviour. One problem to be aware of is that you must allow all the processes in the pipeline to run simultaneously; otherwise, you can end up with processes blocked because their output pipe is full and the process reading it isn't available yet. This might matter more when you have N-part pipelines (N > 2) rather than just 2-part pipelines as at the moment, but that's a reason I think your inner waiting loop is ill-advised. Diagnostic printing helps a lot with process management.

Comment: For the prompt that came back, I made a mistake... And ok for diagnostic printing, it helped me to understand. But I still don't understand this :               
/* These closes are redundant until you remove the inner wait code */
              //close(fd[0]);
              //close(fd[1]);
What did you add it, if it redundant, and why it wouldn't be redundant if I remove the inner wait code?
If you're tired to explain me (who doesn't understand fast), np and thank you again;)

Comment: At the moment, the 'redundant' closes are reclosing the pipes that were closed in the inner wait loop.  You would find that the closes fail with EBADF if you bothered to check the error status and `errno` (most people don't check the status from `close()` most of the time, and it is mostly OK not to do so). It is crucial that the parent shell does close both ends of the pipe.  Otherwise, a process that reads from the pipe won't get EOF (because there is still a process that could write to it).